# making cells blank in and excel sheet using perl

Tags: perl, excel, parsing

I have an excel sheet to which I need to empty some cells

So far this is what it looks like:

I open the sheet, and check for cells not empty in column M. 
I add those cells to my array mistake
and then I would like to make black all those cells and save the file (this step not working), as that file needs to be the input to anotherprogram/
thanks!

```
$infile = $ARGV[0];

 $columns = ReadData($infile) or die "cannot open excel table\n\n";
 print "xls sheet contains $columns->[1]{maxrow} rows\n";

 my $xlsstartrow;
 if ( getExcel( A . 1 ) ne "text" ) {

$xlsstartrow = 2;   
 }
 else 
 {
$xlsstartrow = 4;
 }


 check_templates();
 print "done";
 sub check_templates {

for ( $row = $xlsstartrow ; $row < ( $columns->[1]{maxrow} + 1 ) ; $row++ ) {

    if (getExcel(M . $row) ne ""  ){ 

        $cell = "M" . $row ;

        push(@mistakes,$cell);

    }

}
 rewritesheet(@mistakes);


 }

 sub rewritesheet {


my $FileName = $infile;
 my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
 my $template = $parser->Parse($FileName);
my $worksheet = $template->worksheet(0);


my $row      = 0;
my $col      = 0;
# Get the format from the cell

my $format   = $template->{Worksheet}[$sheet]
                       ->{Cells}[$row][$col]
                        ->{FormatNo};


    foreach (@mistakes){


$worksheet->AddCell( $_, "" ); 
}          

 $template->SaveAs($infile2);`
```

Comment: Which modules do you use to process the Excel file?

Comment: This looks like [Spreadsheet::Read](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Spreadsheet-Read-0.46/Read.pm). Please post a complete script **and** start your script with `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. Then - work out the many error messages and warnings which now will show up. If you can't figure out your problem, try to reduce your program to a few lines (which do only what you ask).

Answer (score 1):

#### Empty column values in an Excel sheet and save the result?

If the whole purpose of your program is to delete all column M values from a .xls file, then the following program (adopted from your program) will do exactly that:

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
  use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;

   my $infile  = $ARGV[0];
  (my $infile2 = $infile) =~ s/(\.xls)$/_2$1/;
   my $parser  = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
   my $workbook = $parser->Parse($infile);

   my $sheet = $workbook->worksheet(0);
   print "xls sheet contains rows \[0 .. $sheet->{MaxRow}\]\n";
   my $startrow = $sheet->get_cell(0, 0) eq 'text' ? 4-1 : 2-1;

   my $col_M = ord('M') - ord('A');
   for my $row ($startrow .. $sheet->{MaxRow}) {
      my $c = $sheet->get_cell($row, $col_M);
      if(defined $c && length($c->value) > 0) { # why check?
         $sheet->AddCell($row, $col_M, undef) # delete value
      }
   }
   $workbook->SaveAs($infile2);
   print "done";
```

But, if you really want to clear out column M only, why would you test for values? You could just overwrite them without test. Maybe thats not all your program is required to perform? I don't know.

Regards

rbo